# Angular 4 async data storage

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm creating a testing application that has 1000s of questions hosted on firebase. To prevent downloading the questions multiple times, I've implemented a questions service where in the constructor I download the questions:

```
this.db.list("questions/", { preserveSnapshot: true}).subscribe(snapshots => {...}
```

This downloads the questions and pushes them to a questions array so that I don't have to re download until the next session. I also have a function to serve the questions:

```
getQuestion(){
    return this.questions[0];
}
```

However, because of the asynchronous nature of firebase, often times the data is not yet downloaded before `getQuestion()` is called, so it returns  undefined.

Is there a proper way to implement this data store type pattern in angular, and make sure the async call in the constructor finishes before `getQuestion()` gets called?

I've tried adding a variable `ready`, initializing it to false, and setting it to true when the async call returns. Then, `getQuestions()` is modified to look like:

```
getQuestion(){
    while(!this.ready()){}
    return this.questions[0];
}
```

However this just causes the app to hang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost never necessary to use `preserveSnapshot`. Not having to worry about snapshots is one of the main benefits of using AngularFire. Just write `this.db.list(PATH).subscribe(list =>`.

You're confusing "downloading" with "subscribing". It is hardly ever a good idea to subscribe inside a service, and store the data locally--you'll never be exactly sure when the subscribe handler has run, as you have found.

Instead, the service should provide an observable, which consumers--usually components-will consume. Those consumers can subscribe to the observable and do whatever they want, include storing the data statically, or, preferably, you can subscribe to the observable directly within a template using the `async` pipe.

The general rule is to subscribe as late as possible--ideally in the template. Write your code as a set of observables which you map and filter and compose.

Firebase caches results and in general you don't need to worry about caching yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Call `getQuestion()` function after Data from `FireBase` was downloaded.
Use blow code:

```
this.db.list("questions/").subscribe(list => {...} //etc
```